# This is the code written according to the official documentation, I do not know which side went wrong

Tags: google-drive-api

```
def downloadFile():
    file_id = ''  # file id
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.FileIO('hello.txt', 'wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret_2.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    downloadFile()
```

This can download files just uploaded via google drive api, but can't download other
This problem bothered me for two days

Comment: This is the error message
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/file_id?alt=media returned "File not found: file_id.">


When i opened this link
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}

Comment: In your situation, I thought that this thread might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/q/57316103

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Google Drive: File list always returns me 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316103/flutter-google-drive-file-list-always-returns-me-0)

Comment: yes,I replaced SCOPES with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly,the problem solved

Comment: @边雨诚 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.